# tikz \draw not defined error inside \lettrine

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, lettrine

Background: I'm using Overleaf as my editor/compiler platform. I don't have a local compiler due to it being a work computer.

I'm trying to add a little image in the upper left corner of a paragraph. Basically it would act like a drop cap but is a tikzpicture instead of a letter. I want to compile my document without errors but this one is tripping me up. Can someone explain why I'm getting an error and how to fix it?

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...ght \space (\begin {tikzpicture} \draw 
                                                  (0,0) rectangle (1.5cm,1.5...
l.18 }{}
        \lipsum[1]% error occurs on this line
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The compiler on Overleaf reports this error which I'm understanding to mean `\draw` is not defined. If you comment out the line with `\draw` on it, the error goes away. Even stranger, as shown in the screenshot and example project, it draws the image anyway.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for example text

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.5cm,1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}% this drawing is fine

\lettrine[lines=4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.5cm,1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{}\lipsum[1]% error occurs on this line

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot from Overleaf]

Here is this example hosted on Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/tpjcwbcpwwmw

Comment: Hello Richard! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Comment: That's fine. I just didn't want to leave out any potentially related information.

Comment: @yo' this example compiles perfect with a local LaTeX installation on my machine, maybe it is an overleaf issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem comes from leaving the second argument blank.  A `\strut` will do.  However, to get rid of the error message, use a savebox.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for example text

\newsavebox{\letterbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\letterbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.5cm,1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\lettrine[lines=4]{\usebox\letterbox}{\strut}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: So many edits to this post. I originally saw the \savebox method and when I tested that on its own it worked without the second argument. Then I saw you edited that out and now edited it back in. Confusing on my side but \savebox seems to do it.

Comment: I tend to tweak my answers, especially if I don't know WHY they work.